# Rails Tutorial (M. Hartl) Chapter 3, Missing `static_pages_controller_test.rb` folder after `rails generate`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I'm working on Michael Hartl's RoR Tutorial Chapter 3.2.1 and I'm generating a Static Pages controller using the command:

```
$ rails generate controller StaticPages home help
```

But after doing this I cannot see the see the `test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb` file being generated like in the book (see tenth line):

```
$ rails generate controller StaticPages home help
      create  app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
       route  get 'static_pages/help'
       route  get 'static_pages/home'
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/static_pages
      create    app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb
      create    app/views/static_pages/help.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/static_pages_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/helpers/static_pages_helper_test.rb
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/static_pages.js.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/static_pages.css.scss
```

Here's what it looks like when I run it:

[image: screenshot]

My folder is also completely empty and cannot run any tests.

Comment: If you've found any of the answers particular useful be sure to select it as 'accepted' by clicking the grey tick so it turns green.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have mixed up editions of Michael Hartl's Ruby On Rails tutorial.

The 3rd edition uses Minitest instead of RSpec. However you app seems to be setup to use RSpec which is a different test framework which was used in the 2nd edition.

If you want to know why its generating RSpec specs instead of tests then its most likely because you ran:

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

Which changes the generators to generate specs instead.

The simplest way to remedy this is to delete your current `sample_app` directory and start over from the beginning of chapter 3 and make sure you only use the current edition:

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages

There are other ways but it might be easier to avoid other mishaps down the line if you get a fresh start.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use rspec for testing and the generator command creates files and folders related to rspec suite. Instead of creating:

> test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb

it creates:

> spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb

so if you want to follow Michael Hartl's RoR Tutorial you must change your testing method to minitest.